# how to create an approval flow with project rights/role rights in sequential approval

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie in php MySQL application development. Currently I am developing a project management application. Daily end user is updating the job update and has a Voucher number for that. This voucher number is to be approved by line managers.
For this, I made two tables. One for project progress update and second for approval sequence to follow. (example 5 approvals for one voucher number). If one approval is completed, it should show second approval of the user has role rights.
For individual files, I can see fetch. But list of pending with user roles is difficult. Please help. Thanks in advance.
Code is below for single vr fetch. I need bulk fetch.

```
select tbl_trans_all_approval.* from tbl_trans_all_approval
                    inner join tbl_role_users on tbl_trans_all_approval.assg_apprv_role = tbl_role_users.apprv_role 
                    inner join tbl_role_job on tbl_trans_all_approval.job_code = tbl_role_job.project_erp_id
                        where tbl_trans_all_approval.app_id = 
                            (select min(tbl_trans_all_approval.app_id) from tbl_trans_all_approval
                             where tbl_trans_all_approval.app_id = (select min(tbl_trans_all_approval.app_id) from tbl_trans_all_approval
                where  tbl_trans_all_approval.vr_no = '8' and tbl_trans_all_approval.app_ind='N'))
                and tbl_trans_all_approval.app_trc_code = 'SJP' and tbl_trans_all_approval.app_ind = 'N' 
                and tbl_role_users.employee_no = '55555' group by job_code;
```

Comment: pls help on my request